# What type of microphone is this?

Tags: microphones, live-sound

I've spotted these microphones (I think they're microphones...) all over the place in live music shows, but have been unable to find anything about them. Anyone know what this is?

[image: mic]

Comment: There is a type of microphone shaped slightly like that -- a pressure zone microphone mounted on a plate to get half-omni pickup -- but I think @kirka has the right answer.

Comment: @keshlam I thought that at first when I saw this also. Of course, if it were a PZM microphone, this would not be an effective setup for it (as PZMs should be set up on a boundary). As it is an antenna, this setup makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a microphone; it's directional antenna for wireless microphone systems. See http://www.shure.com/americas/products/accessories/wireless-systems/wireless-systems-antennas for details.